# Vouvoyer ou tutoyer son supérieur hiérarchique

Tags: politesse, france, vouvoiement, travail, tutoiement

Quelles sont les modalités du vouvoient/tutoiement d'un supérieur hiérarchique ?

Je connais mon superviseur de recherche post-doctorale depuis cinq ans. Il a 50 ans et moi 39 ans. Il est professeur des universités et moi enseignant-chercheur temporaire. Il s'adresse à moi en me tutoyant mais moi à cause d'un certain respect que je crois lui devoir (position hiérarchique, âge), je lui adresse toujours la parole en le vouvoyant. Par exemple, lorsque je lui envoie un e-mail je commence par "Cher Professeur Y (son nom), je vous remercie…".

Est-ce une faute de ma part ? Est-ce, selon les critères culturels français, un  comportement inhabituel ?

Il me faut préciser que d'autres chercheurs (même doctorants de 25 ans)  s'adressent à lui en le tutoyant et en l'appelant par son prénom seulement. "Bonjour X,...".
Je n'arrive pas à comprendre s'il s'agit d'un comportement typique ou si c'est à cause d'un manque de respect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Généralement, tu peux tutoyer un supérieur si tu le connais bien, en fonction du temps passé ensemble, des sorties en dehors du travail...

Ce n'est pas une faute de vouvoyer quelqu'un même s'il te tutoie. Si cela le dérangeait, il te l'aurait fait remarquer en disant quelque chose comme "tu peux me tutoyer".

Mais si tu te sens mal à l'aise vis à vis de lui par rapport au niveau de langage, le mieux est de lui demander. Après la gêne de la question passée tu te sentiras plus à l'aise.

Comment: Le fait que les autres etudiants le tutoient est je pense le signe le plus clair que tu devrais songer a le faire aussi.  Le tutoiement est devenu tres courant dans le monde du travail, et est essentiellement automatique. Il indique qu'on travaille dans la meme compagnie/organization, sans impliquer du tout une intimite particuliere.  De plus, vous n'avez que 10 ans de difference, surtout a vos ages c'est negligeable. Il faut arreter d'etre si coince :-)

Answer (score 0):

**A** Le comportement de base, évidemment est le vouvoiement du supérieur hiérarchique par le subordonné; cependant le supérieur hiérarchique est tenu à la même étiquette et il/elle peut s'attirer des ennuis en se permettant le tutoiement non autorisé ou non consenti; ce type de liberté que puisse prendre un supérieur peut ne pas servir sa réputation.

**B** La formule « Cher Professeur X » me semble une possibilité convenable, mais dernièrement un avis de Stéphane Gimenez m'a contredit assez catégoriquement; en vérité on ne trouve qu'assez rarement « Cher/Chère » employé avec « Monsieur/madame » dans une formule d'appel. Cette combinaison, et d'autres avec « Cher/Chère », semble n'être convenable que lorsque il existe un certain degré d'amitié entre les correspondants, sans pour cela qu'il faille que cette amitié se situe au niveau de la camaraderie. Stéphane Gimenez précise que particulièrement dans la correspondance des étudiants avec leur professeurs le mot « Cher/Chère » n'est jamais utilisé, sauf exceptionnellement dans une lettre de remerciement. Comme la relation que vous entretenez avec votre professeur est certainement empreinte de ce certain degré d'amitié auquel je réfère ci-dessus j'aurais tendance à penser que la formule d'appel que vous utilisez ne détonne pas.

**C** En ce qui concerne le tutoiement de votre professeur par d'autres élèves  il est impossible de penser à du manque de respect; le tutoiement n'est pas un signe de manque de respect mais basiquement un signe de familiarité, ce qui est très différent. Il se trouve seulement qu'une amitié plus étroite s'est développée entre eux. L'amitié est une question d'affinités, il sont français pour la plupart, je le suppose, et les « atome crochus », si l'on peut dire, sont plus efficaces que dans votre cas, comme la culture française n'est toujours pas votre élément naturel.  Il est possible aussi que les « habitudes » en France soient en voie de changement et que le tutoiement soit plus rapidement introduit dans les relations. Cette camaraderie entre les étudiants et leur professeurs ne me semble pas typique cependant et généralement c'est un comportement à proscrire, sauf peut être lorsqu'elle est le résultat d'une longue période pendant laquelle les personnes en question ont pu développer des liens d'amitié plus serrés, mais c'est une chose toujours difficile à concevoir.

Comment: Ne me fais pas dire ce que je n'ai pas dit. Le contexte ici est différent. Pour s'adresser à son superviseur c'est entièrement au choix, et ça dépend des situations. C'est très courant de dire *tu* à tout le monde dans le domaine de la recherche scientifique et d'employer *Cher* dans un e-mail (suivi du prénom), et pour un superviseur en particulier aussi.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez  Je n'étend votre responsabilité qu'à un avis sur la formule d'appel; le reste ressort de mes opinions. En ce qui concerne le tutoiement, je vois que les choses ont bien changé au cours des années passées, comme je m'en doutais un peu.

Comment: Reste que tu me fais dire ce que je n'ai pas dit, même dans le cas de la formule d'appel.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Here is your comment: 
Je tiens à préciser que Cher n'est normalement pas utilisé dans la correspondance formelle (étudiant–professeur en particulier). La lettre de remerciement finale est un cas très particulier, et dans ce cas ça peut être un bon choix. Je vous prie d'accepter blabla ça ne va pas du tout avec des remerciements chaleureux. – Stéphane Gimenez♦ Nov 11 at 12:58

Comment: Il s'agissait d'un étudiant en langue étrangère, pas d'un doctorant qui s'adresse à des collègues qu'il côtoie tous les jours… N'es-tu pas capable de faire la différence ?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez J'avoue que je n'aurais pas jusqu'à présent vu de différence; ça s'explique puisqu'il faut être familier avec la vie universitaire actuelle pour savoir cela et que je ne le suis pas.

Comment: On évite de faire des réponses quand on est pas familier avec un sujet… Et ça ne vaut pas que pour celle-là.

Answer (score 0):

Le fait que les autres étudiants le tutoient est, je pense, le signe le plus clair que tu devrais songer à le faire aussi. Le tutoiement est devenu très courant dans le monde du travail, et est essentiellement automatique. Il indique qu'on travaille dans la meme compagnie/organization, sans impliquer du tout une intimité particulière. De plus, vous n'avez que 10 ans de difference, surtout a vos ages c'est négligeable. Il faut arrêter d'être si coince :-)

[J'ai transformé en réponse le commentaire de l'utilisateur @user13512 ; j'ai ajouté des accents où il était nécessaire.]

Comment: In such a case it might be better to enable "community wiki". Also note you can include a link to a comment, from the timestamp following it i.e. right-click. For instance, [here's the link](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32458/vouvoyer-ou-tutoyer-son-sup%c3%a9rieur-hi%c3%a9rarchique#comment66644_32460) to the comment you included.