# Should I use l'Alliance Française if I want to get a certification in French?

Tags: apprentissage

I am new in French.

In my university I have French classes; they are cool and great but I would like to get some certification in this language and I found in Google **l'Alliance Française**. It is an institute that promote the French language.

Should I use this certification or what?

Comment: Certification towards what? Which country are you in and what line of career are you hoping to have?

Comment: I am from mexico and my work is developer web

Comment: @simon Web developer. Be careful with the different order  between English and French; développeur/développeuse Web. I think that the French order is common in latin-based languages. For instance in Romanian is: Dezvoltator web. In Spanish: desarrollador web. On the other hand in German (as in English and other germanic languages I believe): Web-Entwickler and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the DELF diploma for the levels A1-B2.
You can find easily information by googling.
The principal page is:

http://www.ciep.fr/delf-dalf

or

http://www.ciep.fr/en/delf-dalf

In brief, B1 is the minimum level required by French universities in order to accept a student, although they are some disciplines that they demand level C1 (DALF).

For information about the classification of language levels see here for instance:

https://www.france-langue.fr/niveaux-de-francais/

https://www.coe.int/en/web/common-european-framework-reference-languages/level-descriptions

There are also other diplomas recognized in France and abroad as well such as Test de Connaissance de Langue Française.

http://www.ciep.fr/tcf

Comment: thank you for you information and helpful

Comment: @simon Je vous en prie:-)!

Comment: @dimitris That should be *je t'en prie*. Students don't use *vous* among themselves. Please don't promote the *vouvoiement* which, in my opinion, has been too much used lately in FSE. It doesn't make sense here as all FSE members are peers, *tu* is the standard between peers (outside formal institutions like the *Académie française* or the *Parlement*).

Comment: @jlliagre D'accord:-)! J'ai l'habitude de vouvoyer comme tu as peut-être observé. Je vais adapter le tutoiement. Je te remercie:-)!

Comment: Tu vouvoies tes collègues à l'université ?

Comment: @jlliagre Non ! Mais je demande toujours si je peux tutoyer ou j'attend que l’interlocuteur fasse la première démarche. Hormis bien sur mon superviseur. Voie la question ici https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/32458/vouvoyer-ou-tutoyer-son-sup%C3%A9rieur-hi%C3%A9rarchique

Comment: Dans FSE, tu peux toujours tutoyer tout le monde. On vouvoie les inconnus, par défaut ses supérieurs et professeurs, et les représentants de l'autorité, personnalités, etc. mais ici et plus généralement sur Internet, le vouvoiement est plutôt ridicule.

Comment: @jlliagre Merci encore. Voici une raison pour aimer FSE. On apprend/améliorer "son français" mais on connaît également la culture d'Hexagone:-)!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good description of possible certifications https://www.fle.fr/Les-tests-et-certifications-de-FLE (sorry for the link but there's no way to cut and paste all that).

You can of course get basic certifications via the Alliance Francaise, but beware that it's usually the most expensive solution possible.  And the quality of the teaching is very dependent on the location, so it may not be the best for you.  At the same link, note the resources to prepare yourself online..